# The type HttpServerUtilityBase does not have an accessible constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

I have a service class called ImageUploadService, which handles some complex operations on combining image paths and save images to server. It will require an instance of Controller.Server object at its constructor, which turns out to be from the class HttpServerUtilityBase. I use Unity.MVC5 to manage dependencies, and it gives me me this error:

```
The type HttpServerUtilityBase does not have an accessible constructor.
```

So how do I solve this problem? I feel that this is a bit more complex issue as Controller.Server is not accessible directly inside Controller's constructor and only made available inside controller's action. Anyone know if it is possible to use dependency injection on Controller.Server? If so, how?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: It just gives you that error? Did you have some code that caused it to give you that error, or does Unity.MVC5 simply not like you? Is it a compile-time error, or is it an exception? If it's an exception, then please post the complete exception.

Comment: Well there are quite some details about the error, but it may not help much. If you want to look at more, I've copied/pasted everything to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/kHqwv02E

Comment: I think the issue is that Controller.Server is not available until the controller constructor method finishes execution. Although this gives rises to the question how Controller.Server is generated, it must be coming from somewhere. But where?

Comment: The actual trick is to **not** inject such framework type in your own components at all. This *is* a violation of the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles. If you update your question with more details about what of functionality of the `HttpServerUtilityBase` you need (some code examples including your `ImageUploadService` would be ideal), I'll try to post an answer describing an alternative design that solves your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Using Unity you need to register the `HttpServerUtilityWrapper` as follows:

```
container.RegisterType<HttpServerUtilityBase, HttpServerUtilityWrapper>(
    new TransientLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionConstructor(HttpContext.Current.Server));
```

The key is that the container is configured to call the constructor passing the `HttpContext.Current.Server` object using `InjectionConstructor`.